# Need References That Discuss The Mathematical Number Known as Wau

Tags: calculus

For those not familiar, perhaps this link in which Vi Hart discusses the number will be useful:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFLkou8NvJo

However, I cannot find any sources online that discuss the number. I'm interested in reading further about this mysterious constant but cannot seem to find anything. Is wau a constant or is it a function? If the latter, does it have any relation to the digamma function? [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function]

I'd love to explore some external references [outside the video] if anyone can provide some useful ones pertinent to it. Thank you!

Comment: Wau is another name for digamma..... so yes they are related the same way that something relates to itself

Comment: I think wau in Vi Hart's video is just the number 1 presented in a confusing way.

Comment: You should have listened to the whole video before posting here...

Comment: yeah me too thought its a weird number and ended up reading this post smiling

Answer (score 5):

It's just the number 1. It's pretty clear that's what she's getting at in the video I think it's just meant to be misleading / funny.

Comment: So here's some [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%28number%29)

Comment: @MarkBishop My math is so bad I do not trust myself at all but the video is supposed to be a joke, right?

Answer (score 5):

It might be cool if we work out all the computation in the video. So here is my first go:

$$ \frac{1}{ \frac{3}{\frac{3}{\dots} + \frac{1}{\dots}} + \frac{1}{\frac{3}{\dots} + \frac{1}{\dots}}} = G = \frac{1}{3G+G} $$

So $G=\frac1{2}$ and therefore $F=1$

and the second

$$ F = \frac{5}{6} + \frac{ \frac{5}{6} + \frac{ \frac{5}{6} + \frac{ \frac{5}{6} + \dots}{6}}{6}}{6} = \frac{5}{6} + \frac{F}{6}$$
$$F = \frac{5+F}{6}$$
$$F=1$$